# Grouping on Date difference not getting desired output in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

Data In Table

| CaseNo | DESTCODE | HotelName | CheckInDate | CheckOutDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UD-11323 | Gangtok | Mayfair Spa Resort & Casino | 2022-04-26 | 2022-04-27 |
| UD-11323 | Gangtok | Mayfair Spa Resort & Casino | 2022-04-27 | 2022-04-28 |
| UD-11323 | Lachung | Etho Metho | 2022-04-28 | 2022-04-29 |
| UD-11323 | Gangtok | Mayfair Spa Resort & Casino | 2022-04-29 | 2022-04-30 |

Required Output

| CaseNo | DESTCODE | HotelName | CheckInDate | CheckOutDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UD-11323 | Gangtok | Mayfair Spa Resort & Casino | 2022-04-26 | 2022-04-28 |
| UD-11323 | Lachung | Etho Metho | 2022-04-28 | 2022-04-29 |
| UD-11323 | Gangtok | Mayfair Spa Resort & Casino | 2022-04-29 | 2022-04-30 |

While querying the above data, I used:

```
min(CheckInDate), max(CheckOutDate) using Group by CaseNo,
DESTCODE,HotelName
```

The desired output Pick single record for the HotelName  **"Mayfair Spa Resort & Casino"** and  DestCode **"Gangtok"**

The required output is required as mention, in second table.

Comment: I'm not sure if assuming the OP is using SQL Server (because they tagged [[tag:sql]] and [[tag:server]]) is a safe assumption, @lemon . Though I can't talk for other products, `max(CheckOutDate) using Group by CaseNo` certainly isn't valid T-SQL. `USING GROUP BY` in the `SELECT` isn't part of the syntax.

Comment: Vishwanath Gangaiah , what (R)DBMS are you actually using here? *If* you are using SQL Server, I don't know where you found that syntax, but it's simply not valid; the `GROUP BY` goes after the `WHERE`, not as part of the expression for a column's definition.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SELECT` statement looks incomplete.

In any case, when you're carrying out an aggregation task, you need to define:

- which fields are aggregated: "*CheckInDate*", "*CheckOutDate*"
- which fields are selected: "*CaseNo*", "*DESTCODE*", "*HotelName*"

Then you need to put each non-aggregated field (selected ones) inside the `GROUP BY` clause, to avoid either DBMS exceptions or more subtle errors in your data.

```
SELECT CaseNo, DESTCODE, HotelName,
       MIN(CheckInDate)  AS CheckInDate, 
       MAX(CheckOutDate) AS CheckOutDate
FROM tab
GROUP BY CaseNo, DESTCODE, HotelName
```

This is likely to work on all the most common DBMS products.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but still failed to achieve the same with the query where Gangtok has to repeat twice, but with the above query Gangtok appears only once

Comment: Hey Vishwanath, this is clearly a wrong answer. Although before updating it, knowing your DBMS and the version you're using, is a strict requirement, as every DBMS has deeply different tools to leverage, and there's no single solution that can fit every DBMS.